# How to javac checks the parameterized types

Tags: java, jvm, javac

How to javac checks the parameterized types? I found information about JVM specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1 but the information about generic type is not available at runtime. Or checking algorithm javac similar to algorithm JVM?
Please help me in this question!

Comment: [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: This is not what I need. This description of result, instead of algorithm of its receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Javac checks that the declared types of variables and parameters conform to the generic type specified.
Javac cannot check actual runtime class (for obvious reasons).

Comment: And as javac does it? Me the algorithm description interests.